# Check all values in an array by using a loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 1244
    [2] => 34124
    [3] => 123
)
```

is there a loop that will check if the values in my array are equal to each other?

Comment: `foreach()` php loop method

Comment: The answer to your question is:  Yes.

Comment: try this `if(count($array) !== count(array_unique($array))( {  } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give you the count of each value

```
$array = array("123", "1244","34124","123");

$cnt_array = array_count_values($array)

echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($cnt_array);

$res = array();
foreach($cnt_array as $key=>$val){
   if($val == 1){
      $res[$key] = 'unique';
   }
   else{
      $res[$key] = 'duplicate';
   }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```